# Can you have different background colours for each tab in a UITabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a tab bar with three items, and at the moment I'm setting the background colour for all three with the following:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:242.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

I would like to use a different colour for the middle tab, but can't find a way to specify this.

To be clear I'd like a tab bar that looks like the following (dark blue in the middle and light blue either side):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this the safe answer would be to change the tab bar's tint color when each controller is made visible. If you app is simple, you could do this in `viewDidAppear:` as…

```
@implementation MyChildViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = ...; // Whatever this controller's color is
}

@end
```